# computer-forensics タグのタグ wiki 抜粋について

Tags: 討議

先ほど 豚吐露 さんからタグ wiki 抜粋の編集の提案があり、最近 [forensic](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/forensic) というタグが[この質問](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/42241/19110)で作られたことを知りました。

同名のタグが本家 Stack Overflow に無いか探したところ、本家では [[computer-forensics]](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/computer-forensics/info) という名前になっているようでしたので、私がタグを [computer-forensics](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/computer-forensics) に付け替えました。

しかし付け替えた後、これだと 豚吐露 さんから頂いていた編集の提案が無駄になってしまうことに気づきました。そこで 豚吐露 さんにお願いなのですが、同様の提案を [computer-forensics](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/computer-forensics) にも頂けませんでしょうか？

念の為、頂いていた編集の提案の内容をこちらにも転記しておきます。

> コンピュータ・フォレンジクス(computer forensics)、デジタル・フォレンジクス(digital forensics)、フォレンジクス(forensics)のこと。デジタルデータの解析を行い証拠を取得すること。転じて、CTFなどでは、デジタルデータを解析して目的の情報を取得する問題の分野を指す。